# ApolloServer (NodeJS): Return string response

Tags: node.js

I have an ApolloServer with default settings such as:

```
class AuditRemoteGraphQLDataSource extends RemoteGraphQLDataSource {
   ...
}
const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
    serviceList,
    buildService: ({url}) => new AuditRemoteGraphQLDataSource({url})
});

const server = new ApolloServer({
    debug: false,
    gateway,
    context: async ({req}) => {
    .........
}
```

Upon making a request (query/mutation), we expect:
{
"data": {
"something": "somevalue"
}
}

This works fine. The challenge I am having is that for a specific GET request, I want to return a string as is. I tried to extend:

```
 async didReceiveResponse(response, req, context) {
        const body = await super.didReceiveResponse(response, req, context);
        body.data = "someString";
        return body;
    }
```

But it did not help.

Comment: It'll be easier for others to understand what you trying to achieve if you post the any sample data or some code written inside `didReceiveResponse`.

Comment: OK done. Hopefully you will be able to help me.

Comment: you said `{ "data": { "something": "somevalue" } }` this works, that means your schema defines `data` to be an object, if that's the case then you cannot return 'string' like this inside data `body.data = "someString";` it will not match your graphql schema.

Comment: If this is not the case for you, please include more details about your schema as well.

Comment: It will not match my schema, and this is the challenge I am facing. I do not want to use this method specifically. It was one of the tries I had. Do you have an alternative.